# ggplot2: does boxplot use for calculations only values lying within limits of y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, median, boxplot

I noticed that median of boxplot (constructed with restricted ylim-parameter) may differ from the median obtained by median()-function or boxplot without adjusted y-axis.

Does it mean that boxplot use for calculations only values lying within defined interval of y-axis??
And if so, how could I get correct boxplot (based on all values), but plot it on particular interval of y.axis??

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `ylim` restricts the scale for `y`. In ggplot, data that falls outside the scale's limits is discarded and is not included in any statistical computations (such as boxplots). To just zoom the axes without changing the data that is included, use `coord_cartesian(ylim=...)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was quite not obvious for me.

Comment: This also helped me today. Good answer.

Comment: Wow!!  Thanks so much!  I'm curious, is this a "feature" or "bug"?  I never realized that ylim worked this way, and am worried about mistakes I must have made in the past.  If this is the desired behavior, I think some strong verbiage should explain this in the documentation.